# JS Display a button when an element is Disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

First time here ...
Im a beginner in JS .

I want to display an input only when another input has a disabled attribute:

```
<button type="button" id="Last"> Last </button>
<button type="button" id="Go" style="display:none"> Go </button>
```

after few click,  and using jQuery, `$("#Last").attr("disabled", "disabled"),` I get (using the inspect tool) :

```
<button type="button" id="last" disabled="disabled"> Last </button>
```

I want to display this:

```
 <button type="button" id="Go" style="display:block"> Go </button>
```

I tried this:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  if($("#Last").prop('disabled', true)) {
        $('#Go').show();
  } else {
        $('#Go').hide();
  }
});
```

I doesn't work! Dont know where is the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show the button when the button is clicked. See the commented code below.

```js
// When button is clicked
$("#last").on("click", function() {

  // Set button disabled to true
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);

  // Show the #go button
  $("#go").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="last"> Last </button>

<button type="button" id="go" style="display:none"> Go </button>
```

I have changed to ids to all lowercase. That is a [good coding convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735650/why-is-lower-case-with-dashes-the-standard-for-html-classes).

Comment: the `Last` button is set to `disabled` when it reach the last click (using jquery), I want to detect if that true, then display the second button

Comment: @JoneSmith can you paste the piece of code in your question which is setting disabled property on the `#last button`?

Comment: Yes, `... if some conditions are correct, then do this   ... 
 $("#Last").attr("disabled", "disabled"),
...  
`

Comment: @JoneSmith then just add this line `$("#go").show();` just below `$("#Last").attr("disabled", "disabled")` and it should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

as describe in the doc at this link http://api.jquery.com/prop/ the method prop(name, xxx) set the property name to the value xxx, o in your code the if statement is disabling the button last. You should use:
`if($("#Last").prop('disabled')) 
  $('#Go').show();`

Be carefull that if you place this piece of code in `$( document ).ready` it only run once the page DOM is ready for JavaScript code to execute.