# What are the different kinds of cases?

Tags: case, naming, camelcasing

I'm interested in the different kinds of identifier cases, and what people call them. Do you know of any additions to this list, or other alternative names?

- `myIdentifier` : Camel case (e.g. in java variable names)
- `MyIdentifier` : Capital camel case (e.g. in java class names)
- `my_identifier` : Snake case (e.g. in python variable names)
- `my-identifier` : Kebab case (e.g. in racket names)
- `myidentifier` : Flat case (e.g. in java package names)
- `MY_IDENTIFIER` : Upper case (e.g. in C constant names)

Comment: My1d3nT1F13r : Leet case ^_^

Comment: Why is it called kebab-case? Where did the name come from?

Comment: Imagine a shish-kebab being run through the identifier.

Comment: to correct @AustinCoryBart 's response about shish-kebab, imagine a **skewer** being run through the identifier. The dash (`-`) between words resembles the skewer, and the words resemble to the meat and vegetables on the shish-kebab skewer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273282/whats-the-name-for-dash-separated-case and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/104468/if-this-is-camelcase-what-is-this for kebab-case variants and others.

Comment: @AustinCoryBart shish (actually spelt şiş) means skewer in Turkish

Comment: How about basket#case? :D

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Letter_case-separated_words

Comment: what.is.this.case?

Comment: Don't forget SpoNGebOBcaSe!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Names are either generic, after a language, or colorful; most don’t have a standard name outside of a specific community.

There are many names for these naming conventions (names for names!); see [Naming convention: Multiple-word identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Multiple-word_identifiers), particularly for [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) (UpperCamelCase, lowerCamelCase). However, many don’t have a standard name. Consider the Python style guide [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) – it calls them by generic names like “lower_case_with_underscores”.

One convention is to name after a well-known use. This results in:

- PascalCase
- MACRO_CASE (C preprocessor macros)

…and suggests these names, which are not widely used:

- c_case (used in K&R and in the standard library, like size_t)
- lisp-case, css-case
- COBOL-CASE

Alternatively, there are illustrative names, of which the best established is CamelCase. [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) is more recent (2004), but is now well-established. kebab-case is yet more recent and still not established, and may have originated on Stack Overflow! ([What's the name for dash-separated case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273282/whats-the-name-for-dash-separated-case)) There are many more colorful suggestions, like caterpillar-case, Train-case (initial capital), caravan-case, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "caterpillar-case" instead of "caterpillar_case"?

Answer (score 101):

- `flatcase` or `mumblecase`
- `kebab-case`. Also called `caterpillar-case`, `param-case`, `dash-case`, `hyphen-case`, `lisp-case`,  `spinal-case` and `css-case`
- `camelCase`
- `PascalCase` or `CapitalCamelCase`
- `snake_case` or `c_case`
- [`CONSTANT_CASE`](https://github.com/blakeembrey/change-case#constantcase), `MACRO_CASE`, `UPPER_CASE` or `SCREAM_CASE`
- `COBOL-CASE` or `TRAIN-CASE`

Comment: mumblecase is quite a nice alternative for flatcase

Comment: howWOULDyouCALLthisCASE?

Comment: IhaveNOidea @encePence

Comment: @encePence iambCASE

Comment: What about `Ada_Case` or `Pascal_Snake_Case`?

Comment: What would you call something in camelCase with a leading underscore, such as `_abcField123`?

Comment: _iDontKnow @Panzercrisis

Comment: `_travestyCase` @Panzercrisis

Answer (score 22):

```
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Formatting               | Name(s)                                                     |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------|
| namingidentifier         | flat case/Lazy Case                                         |
| NAMINGIDENTIFIER         | upper flat case                                             |
| namingIdentifier         | (lower) camelCase, dromedaryCase                            |
| NamingIdentifier         | (upper) CamelCase, PascalCase, StudlyCase, CapitalCamelCase |
| naming_identifier        | snake_case, snake_case, pothole_case, C Case                |
| Naming_Identifier        | Camel_Snake_Case                                            |
| NAMING_IDENTIFIER        | SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE, MACRO_CASE, UPPER_CASE, CONSTANT_CASE |
| naming-identifier        | Kebab Case/caterpillar-case/dash-case, hyphen-case,         |
|                          | lisp-case, spinal-case and css-case                         |
| NAMING-IDENTIFIER        | TRAIN-CASE, COBOL-CASE, SCREAMING-KEBAB-CASE                |
| Naming-Identifier        | Train-Case, HTTP-Header-Case                                |
| _namingIdentifier        | Undercore Notation (prefixed by "_" followed by camelCase   |
| datatypeNamingIdentifier | Hungarian Notation (variable names Prefixed by metadata     |
|                          | data-types which is out-dated)                              |
|--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 8):

`MyVariable` : `Pascal Case` => Used for `Class`

`myVariable` : `Camel Case` => Used for `variable` at Java, C#, etc.

`myvariable` : `Flat Case` => Used for `package` at Java, etc.

`my_variable` : `Snake Case` => Used for `variable` at Python, PHP, etc.

`my-variable` : `Kebab Case` => Used for `css`

Answer (score 1):

**The most common case types:**
*Camel case
Snake case
Kebab case
Pascal case
Upper case (with snake case)*

**camelCase**
camelCase must (1) start with a lowercase letter and (2) the first letter of every new subsequent word has its first letter capitalized and is compounded with the previous word.

An example of camel case of the variable `camel case var` is `camelCaseVar`.

**snake_case**
snake_case is as simple as replacing all spaces with a "_" and lowercasing all the words. It's possible to snake_case and mix camelCase and PascalCase but imo, that ultimately defeats the purpose.

An example of snake case of the variable `snake case var` is `snake_case_var`.

**kebab-case**
kebab-case is as simple as replacing all spaces with a "-" and lowercasing all the words. It's possible to kebab-case and mix camelCase and PascalCase but that ultimately defeats the purpose.

An example of kebab case of the variable `kebab case var` is `kebab-case-var`.

**PascalCase**
PascalCase has every word starts with an uppercase letter (unlike camelCase in that the first word starts with a lowercase letter).

An example of pascal case of the variable `pascal case var` is `PascalCaseVar`.

Note: It's common to see this confused for camel case, but it's a separate case type altogether.

**UPPER_CASE_SNAKE_CASE**
UPPER_CASE_SNAKE_CASE is replacing all the spaces with a "_" and converting all the letters to capitals.

an example of upper case snake case of the variable `upper case snake case var` is `UPPER_CASE_SNAKE_CASE_VAR`.

Comment: UPPER_CASE_SNAKE_CASE also known as SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE

Answer (score 1):

For Python specifically, it is best to use `snake_case` for variable and function names, `UPPER_CASE` for constants (even though we don't have any keywords that specifically say that our variable is a constant) and `PascalCase` for class names.

`camelCase` is not recommended for Python (although languages such as Javascript have it as their main casing), and `kebab-case` would be invalid as Python names cannot contain a hypen (`-`).

```py
variable_name = 'Hello World!'

def function_name():
    pass

CONSTANT_NAME = 'Constant Hello World!!'

class ClassName:
    pass
```