# How to handle a function return type conditioned by the parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function for changing object key casing:

```js
export enum CasingPattern {
  SNAKE,
  CAMEL,
}

export const toSnakeCase = (camelCased: string) => {
  const replaced = camelCased.replace(
    new RegExp(CAMEL_CASE_PATTERN, 'g'),
    (match) => {
      const arr = match.split('');
      const last = arr.pop();
      const parsed = arr.join('') + '_' + last?.toLowerCase();
      return parsed;
    },
  );

  return replaced;
};

export const toCamelCase = (snakeCased: string) => {
  const replaced = snakeCased.replace(
    new RegExp(SNAKE_CASE_PATTERN, 'g'),
    (match) => {
      const [lastLetter, firstLetter] = match.split('_');
      const capitalize = firstLetter.toUpperCase();
      return lastLetter + capitalize;
    },
  );

  return replaced;
};

export const jsonCasingParser = (
  jsonPayload: unknown,
  targetPattern: CasingPattern,
) => {
  const isString = typeof jsonPayload === 'string';
  const stringified = isString ? jsonPayload : JSON.stringify(jsonPayload);

  const replaced = stringified.replace(
    new RegExp(JSON_VARIABLE_PATTERN, 'g'),
    (match) => {
      if (targetPattern === CasingPattern.SNAKE) {
        return toSnakeCase(match);
      }

      if (targetPattern === CasingPattern.CAMEL) {
        return toCamelCase(match);
      }

      return match;
    },
  );

  if (isString) {
    return replaced;
  }

  const parsed = JSON.parse(replaced);

  return parsed;
};
```

CONDITIONS:

1. if a string is passed to `jsonPayload`(an object stringified), it should return a string
2. if an object is passed to `jsonPayload` and the `targetPattern` is `CasingPattern.CAMEL` the return type should be the `jsonPayload` object with their property keys transformed to **camelCase**,
3. if an object is passed to `jsonPayload` and the `targetPattern` is `CasingPattern.SNAKE` the return type should be the `jsonPayload` object with their properties transformed to **snake_case**

```
jsonCasingParser('{ "propOne": "one" }', CasingPattern.CAMEL) // return string
jsonCasingParser({ propOne: "one" }', CasingPattern.SNAKE) // return { prop_one: string } 
jsonCasingParser({ prop_one: "one" }', CasingPattern.CAMEL) // return { propOne: string }
```

I should get one narrowed type depending on the parameters passed to `jsonCasingParser` function.

Comment: A basic typing would be to simply accurately type jsonPayload `(jsonPayload: string | object, targetPattern: CasingPattern ): typeof jsonPayload => {`. For a more complex solution you would need to show your types for of your casing functions but you can look at similar packages for examples ie. [sindresorhus/camelcase-keys](https://github.com/sindresorhus/camelcase-keys/blob/main/index.d.ts)

Comment: @pilchard I updated the question info with those utilities

Comment: You can usually do this using the right construction of generics, mapped types, and indexing. Also, refer [microsoft/TypeScript#33014 (Suggestion for Dependent-Type-Like Functions: Conservative Narrowing of Generic Indexed Access Result Type)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Could you create an answer with the details? Some similar questions suggest using function overloading, but I think the approach you suggest could handle this scenario in a better way.

Comment: I will try to get to it on Monday. I give jcalz and Alex Wayne permission to poach this answer, though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a lot to make this happen. Thankfully someone already did most of the work here, but it's not really everything we need: [TypeScript convert generic object from snake to camel case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269936/typescript-convert-generic-object-from-snake-to-camel-case). First, we are going to need some typescript utilities to convert strings from `camel > snake` and `snake > camel`.

```
type SnakeToCamelString<S extends string | number | Symbol> =
  S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ?
  `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelString<U>>}` :
  S;

type CamelToSnakeString<S extends string | number | Symbol> =
  S extends `${infer T}${infer U}` ?
  `${T extends Capitalize<T> ? "_" : ""}${Lowercase<T>}${CamelToSnakeString<U>}` :
  S;
```

Then we are going to need some utilities to change the casing of all of the keys of an object. I modified the ones from the link above to be recursive:

```
type SnakeToCamelObject<O extends object> = {
  [K in keyof O as SnakeToCamelString<K>]: O[K] extends object ? SnakeToCamelObject<O[K]> : O[K]
}

type CamelToSnakeObject<O extends object> = {
  [K in keyof O as CamelToSnakeString<K>]: O[K] extends object ? CamelToSnakeObject<O[K]> : O[K];
}
```

Then you will need to write overloads for your method to return the correct type based on the arguments. Overloading can be tricky at first - [read more about it in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
function jsonCasingParser(jsonPayload: string, targetPattern: CasingPattern): string;
function jsonCasingParser<T extends object>(jsonPayload: T, targetPattern: CasingPattern.SNAKE): CamelToSnakeObject<T>;
function jsonCasingParser<T extends object>(jsonPayload: T, targetPattern: CasingPattern.CAMEL): SnakeToCamelObject<T>;
function jsonCasingParser<T extends object>(jsonPayload: string | T, targetPattern: CasingPattern) {
  const isString = typeof jsonPayload === 'string';
  const stringified = isString ? jsonPayload : JSON.stringify(jsonPayload);
  
  // ... do the replacement stuff

  // This part is important. The logic here must match your overloads above.
  // TypeScript cannot validate this part for you... so be diligent.
  if (isString) return stringified;
  if (targetPattern === CasingPattern.SNAKE) return JSON.parse(stringified) as CamelToSnakeObject<T>;
  return JSON.parse(stringified) as SnakeToCamelObject<T>;
}
```

Finally, test your code and stare in awe at what TypeScript can do:

```
const stringSnake = jsonCasingParser('{}', CasingPattern.SNAKE); // string
const stringCamel = jsonCasingParser('{}', CasingPattern.CAMEL); // string

const objectSnake = jsonCasingParser({ fooBar: 'bing', nested: { fooBar: 'bing' } }, CasingPattern.SNAKE);
objectSnake.foo_bar; // YAY
objectSnake.nested.foo_bar; // YAY

const objectCamel = jsonCasingParser({ foo_bar: 'bing', nested: { foo_bar: 'bing' } }, CasingPattern.CAMEL);
objectCamel.fooBar; // YAY
objectCamel.nested.fooBar; // YAY
```

[Here's a fully working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=47&ssc=34&pln=38&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgZwJYgOYAU4BcvAE4hQDeAUFFAMoByAggNICiANGbDQLIMAyLAviSSwBPAA7BKIOAGtgAFQD28CMAA2FLHhSoAPBSjAAHrhAATBFAQatUAD5RwEAEb5blIU-kqAfFAC8rPUNjMygAAwASIhQAMxdZXgB9SJiXAFVeUKgAflYIonjI+BEkLDgVJAAvYF1JGQUlVXVNNG1Ury8MqAAuAIBuAWExWDhlFQUKWuAmrV19I1AQy2bUVwdnPFcKd0dPH39yQPnTczyUjYKokFiN9Myc8jzZOeDzIpKyyurZHyyoACIEn9uv8-rxIlx5AB3fAAY0QXw6hRGqnGk2mLTanR6B36glE4gm0jkimRKgA8o4AFbAGFYbRk54LczyKk0rB7YisADadCgKCgMiE8miUAZiAkRPqpPROjoXgAul1RTz5YzjlAWdTadkJXUSaMKVq6WSVT4lSa6PKSPw8UMGmN5ISZIa2fS1SFNWyOaRyDy+YRBcLRVBxfbUUSZdo5YrlZb3czWdrfmHHZMXbT6abgRb5f0bdEwCBaUh5IRKQhS-BkGhMHgEPgABTl0uYIQqeRwExKpZaJhQUp4VDALCYHD4EBKqtaUe4AgASm7VjQ-QLRawJbLFZAU5rcDr+G0TyCTI1ifZTa3rfbnaVsj7A6HI+ws4nw2rGGf44AdNR6AwF8Mozhs6Z6Hl4K6FsWpZQM226INOe71ngh7xqeRpeBeLZwG2HZdlAd79nuj4zuOk7wbuY4EF+MAcNwAFOsS9rpnS3wQWuG4wVuO4fvuyFHkcHpnhhsFXrhi7LK4BEPsOJEEGR76ySAc6cuQMKlpYfIIDKfj9viQYidh14mH4vi+FAADkPZoOZ-SqepWAWEuqBINESDAMZZlIFpTk6gZOGdsCABSFBklQX5Wc50RCJhICiZ2c62VArAAPTJVAX4ZVAJjyP2AAW4h4MAIgqHAMLAMoIAOZYYDRNEAjkC5UANl5MrKYVWBgAQjnLC5bkmIljUNtJT6UYQplmdxik-rQjBtcOnWEMFoVfiIiHAA2EW9e5ymhqSwHAMxYGJe1C1QEtYWrfuG1OVtJg7eYDFSgaoGsdaAhqSAGkRQxOmwZNa14A25lELw5l9v9o3TX+CUkB9X1Ofav1ceRPFIUDINg2+CGQzRnBcDDsP2WhbI-WZf0o7WaNEFA0TyPIABCe5KuZjhaJjIDAJY7lKtTtMM0zFms9ZUC8CL4MU5+VG-rN-SerSDFfnzCSOHuvRQKlUAAJo0JrJBy1gCsc1zJiK3Tyuq+raXa7rhOfQ5+uI2TyMKQDDa82bKt4MzQuoOznO4Hh7vyObXuC2zIti1jFEvtRtH47LZ72qb-N4GrGvW3riekl+RsB8njOp5bWs60AA)

**UPDATE:** Apparently you *can* overload arrow functions as described here: [Typescript overload arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187614/typescript-overload-arrow-functions). However, I was unable to get it to work. [Here's a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgZwJYgOYAU4BcvAE4hQDeAUFFAMoByAggNICiANGbDQLIMAyLAviSSwBPAA7BKIOAGtgAFQD28CMAA2FLHhSoAPBSjAAHrhAATBFAQatUAD5RwEAEb5blIU-kqAfFAC8rPUNjMygAAwASIhQAMxdZXgB9SJiXAFVeUKgAflYIonjI+BEkLDgVJAAvYF1JGQUlVXVNNG1Ury8MqAAuAIBuAWExWDhlFQUKWuAmrV19I1AQy2bUVwdnPFcKd0dPH39yQPnTczyUjYKokFiN9Myc8jzZOeDzIpKyyurZHyyoACIEn9uv8-rxIlx5AB3fAAY0QXw6hRGqnGk2mLTanR6B36glE4gm0jkimRKgA8o4AFbAGFYbRk54LczyKk0rB7YisADadCgKCgMiE8miUAZiAkRPqpPROjoXgAul1RTz5YzjlAWdTadkJXUSaMKVq6WSVT4lSa6PKSPw8UMGmN5ISZIa2fS1SFNWyOaRyDy+YRBcLRVBxfbUUSZdo5YrlZb3czWdrfmHHZMXbT6abgRb5f0bYNxAApChkqjwZBoTB4BAuXyc8gACkpCHkIEwQhU8jgJiVSy0TCgpTwqGAWEwOHwICV5a049wBAAlL2rGh+uRtE8gkyNYn2U2W224B2uz2oLIB0OR2PsPOp8MKxgb5OAHTUegMJfDUbh527jdeNcoA3eMdyNLx91bdtO27JVz0HOBh1HOdJ2nRBZyfAhnxgDhuE-J1iXtdM6W+PMSBhVtLCgZtWxnSsEJrPAlWLUtaMfatayAzcjg9XdwOow9jxgiwVxWOw4MvJCMLvVjkMXPwfB9KByJASikAQGU-EHfEg34qCTz8Xw6wAcj7NAjMA5TKNM1AkGiJBgBMTS1I035dKPaDHKYksqGfazbKECCBI8hdANYAB6MKoGfaKoBMeRBwAC3EPBgBEFQ4BhYBlBALBhLAaJogEchbKgBtnJEhcoBSrAwAIYTlls+yTEAkqGwk68Jzqwy6xkqTX1oRhKuq2rCGYnyRHo4AGz8uyHMq0NSR-YAiP-QDhrqsbnwm9jppExq5pDcx8KlA0-xI60BEs3LrPwzT+N69i8AbIyiF4IyB16zqQH698QrIijrpE+07oPB6GOe173vvdCvqwnCuD+-6VNyz1aVuut7rQujHobIgoGieR5AAIQQpUjMcLQoZAYBLAcpU8YJ4nSagcnKagXh2Y+rHH1ht9Bv6VGsHw59GYSRwEN6KAIqgABNGgZZIQXhep2mTBFwmxYlqXIrlhWkcowXgYx0HuarcGGY18XGJZimzIHFXcFPC35E163WbM9nOehujYewzgEYF3d7XVpm8El6XdcVoPSWfB2HJDkmw+12X5aAA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it's working perfectly. A side question, Is there any other approach where I don't have to change the implementation to a function declaration?

Comment: Unfortunately not. That's a syntax limitation required for overloading.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect information about overloading arrow functions.

Answer (score -1):

To handle a function return type conditioned by the parameters in TypeScript, you can use function overloads. This allows you to specify multiple function signatures for a single function, and TypeScript will choose the correct signature based on how the function is called.

Here's how you can define the overloaded signatures for your jsonCasingParser function:

```
export enum CasingPattern {
  SNAKE,
  CAMEL,
}

// Overload signatures
export function jsonCasingParser(jsonPayload: string, targetPattern: CasingPattern): string;
export function jsonCasingParser(jsonPayload: Record<string, any>, targetPattern: CasingPattern.CAMEL): Record<string, any>;
export function jsonCasingParser(jsonPayload: Record<string, any>, targetPattern: CasingPattern.SNAKE): Record<string, any>;

// Function implementation
export function jsonCasingParser(
  jsonPayload: unknown,
  targetPattern: CasingPattern,
): string | Record<string, any> {
  const isString = typeof jsonPayload === 'string';
  const stringified = isString ? jsonPayload as string : JSON.stringify(jsonPayload);

  const replaced = stringified.replace(
    new RegExp(JSON_VARIABLE_PATTERN, 'g'),
    (match) => {
      if (targetPattern === CasingPattern.SNAKE) {
        return toSnakeCase(match);
      }

      if (targetPattern === CasingPattern.CAMEL) {
        return toCamelCase(match);
      }

      return match;
    },
  );

  if (isString) {
    return replaced;
  }

  const parsed = JSON.parse(replaced);

  return parsed;
}
```

With these overloads, TypeScript will infer the correct return type based on how you call the function:

If you pass in a string for jsonPayload, the return type will always be string.
If you pass in an object for jsonPayload and CasingPattern.CAMEL for targetPattern, the return type will be Record<string, any>.
If you pass in an object for jsonPayload and CasingPattern.SNAKE for targetPattern, the return type will also be Record<string, any>.

If you want to avoid the use of any, you can try something like this:

```
export enum CasingPattern {
  SNAKE,
  CAMEL,
}

// Helper types for transforming keys
type SnakeToCamel<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}`
  ? `${T}${Capitalize<U>}`
  : S;
type CamelToSnake<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}${Uppercase<infer U>}`
  ? `${T}_${Lowercase<U>}`
  : S;

type TransformKeys<T, Pattern> = {
  [K in keyof T as Pattern extends CasingPattern.CAMEL ? SnakeToCamel<string & K> : CamelToSnake<string & K>]: T[K];
};

export function jsonCasingParser(jsonPayload: string, targetPattern: CasingPattern): string;
export function jsonCasingParser<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(jsonPayload: T, targetPattern: CasingPattern.CAMEL): TransformKeys<T, CasingPattern.CAMEL>;
export function jsonCasingParser<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(jsonPayload: T, targetPattern: CasingPattern.SNAKE): TransformKeys<T, CasingPattern.SNAKE>;

// Function implementation
export function jsonCasingParser(
  jsonPayload: unknown,
  targetPattern: CasingPattern,
): string | Record<string, unknown> {
  // ... rest of your implementation remains the same
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: There is a different approach to avoid `any` type? also, I would like to return an object keys transformed, in the response you are returning any object...

Comment: Added an alternate approach...