# Json.Net Is converting on its own before using my JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net, deserialization

In my WPF code, I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize json into my models. First, I receive a Json string ('json') which I then parse into 'message'. (The object I want to deserialize is wrapped in a "data" field in the json string).

```
Activity message = JObject.Parse(json)["data"].ToObject<Activity>();
```

My Activity class uses several [JsonProperty] attributes to generate its fields. One of them is an enum called 'ActivityType'.

```
[JsonProperty("type")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(ActivityTypeConverter))]
public ActivityType Type { get; set; }

public enum ActivityType {
    EmailOpen,
    LinkClick,
    Salesforce,
    Unsupported
};

public class ActivityTypeConverter : JsonConverter {

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var rawString = existingValue.ToString().ToLower();
        if (rawString.Contains("click"))
            return ActivityType.LinkClick;
        else if (rawString.Contains("salesforce"))
            return ActivityType.Salesforce;
        else if (rawString.Contains("email_open"))
            return ActivityType.EmailOpen;
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("unsupported " + rawString);
            return ActivityType.Unsupported;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return !objectType.Equals(typeof(ActivityType));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What's bizarre and frustrating is that json objects which I know have "type":"email_open" are being deserialized as ActivityType.Unsupported, even though my converter should be deserializing them as EmailOpen.

Debugging has shown what the problem is:
the json field "type" is automatically deserializing "email_open" as EmailOpen **and then** it is sent through my converter. (It breaks then because my conditional checks for an underscore, while EmailOpen.ToString() doesn't have one.)

---

**So my question then is:** Why is it converting without my converter and how do I stop it? I just want it to only use my converter

Comment: Shouldn't that be `objectType.Equals(typeof(ActivityType)` (no `!` in front)?  (Or just `objectType == typeof(ActivityType)`)?

Comment: @dbc I don't want it to convert if it's already an ActivityType. That was my attempt to stop double conversions. (Didn't change anything because as I found out, the first conversion doesn't even use my converter)

Comment: As an alternative to rolling your own converter, see [Howto decorate JSON.NET StringEnumConverter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908204/howto-decorate-json-net-stringenumconverter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your converter is being called -- it's just not working.  The problem is that, rather than reading the new value from the `JsonReader reader`, you are using the value from the `existingValue`.  But this second value is the pre-existing property value in the class being deserialized, *not* the value being read.

You need to load the value from the reader along the lines of Json.NET's [`StringEnumConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/StringEnumConverter.cs).  Here's a version that does that and also handles standard values of your enum by subclassing `StringEnumConverter` and passing the value read from the file to the base class for further processing:

```
public class ActivityTypeConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        bool isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);
        Type type = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            if (!isNullable)
                throw new JsonSerializationException();
            return null;
        }

        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            var rawString = ((string)token).ToLower();
            if (rawString.Contains("click"))
                return ActivityType.LinkClick;
            else if (rawString.Contains("salesforce"))
                return ActivityType.Salesforce;
            else if (rawString.Contains("email_open"))
                return ActivityType.EmailOpen;
        }

        using (var subReader = token.CreateReader())
        {
            while (subReader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)
                subReader.Read();
            try
            {
                return base.ReadJson(subReader, objectType, existingValue, serializer); // Use base class to convert
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ActivityType.Unsupported;
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(ActivityType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see, you're right, I mistook the existingValue for the preconverted value. It was probably EmailOpen because enums are non nullable and that was the first option(?). Anyway, everything works nicely now, thank you!