# Json.net Custom enum converter

Tags: c#, json, enums, json.net

I'm currently using Json.net to consume json in my app.
The API I use send me a specific string format for enum for example:

For an enum of type **`TemperatureType`** with values **`fahrenheit, Celcius`**

The json value is:
`{"result":["TemperatureType_fahrenheit","TemperatureType_Celcius"]}`

I would like to use a converter to directly manage it to get 
an `IList<TemperatureType>` but also working for other enum types.

Does anybody have an idea ?

I've try to use a custom JsonConverter :

```
  if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String && reader.Value != null)
  {
      string value = reader.Value.ToString();
      var splitValues = value.Split('_');
      if (splitValues.Length == 2)
      {
         var type = Type.GetType(splitValues[0]);
         return Enum.Parse(type, splitValues[1]);
      }
  }
```

The problem is the GetType Property because I haven't got parameters indicating the desired type and no namespace

Comment: 1) Your JSON seems invalid.  Shouldn't there be a `{"` at the beginning?  2) Is this a duplicate of [Howto decorate JSON.NET StringEnumConverter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908204/howto-decorate-json-net-stringenumconverter)?

Comment: its just a part of my Json reponse (one of the json contained value)
Concerning the decoration, I've seen the thread, but I do not want to add string decorator if possible to avoid errors by developers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The enum type is the `objectType` argument to [`ReadJson`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm).  However, a few points:

1. You need to handle nullable enum types.
2. You need to handle [`[Flag]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229062.aspx) enumerations.  Json.NET writes these as comma-separated lists of values.
3. You need to handle the case of an enum with an invalid value.  Json.NET writes these as numeric values when `StringEnumConverter.AllowIntegerValues == true` and throws an exception otherwise.

Here is a subclass of [`StringEnumConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/StringEnumConverter.cs) that handles these cases by calling the base class then adding or removing the type prefix when appropriate:

```
public class TypePrefixEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        bool isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);
        Type enumType = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("type {0} is not a enum type", enumType.FullName));
        var prefix = enumType.Name + "_";

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            if (!isNullable)
                throw new JsonSerializationException();
            return null;
        }

        // Strip the prefix from the enum components (if any).
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            token = (JValue)string.Join(", ", token.ToString().Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).Select(s => s.StartsWith(prefix) ? s.Substring(prefix.Length) : s).ToArray());
        }

        using (var subReader = token.CreateReader())
        {
            while (subReader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)
                subReader.Read();
            return base.ReadJson(subReader, objectType, existingValue, serializer); // Use base class to convert
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var array = new JArray();
        using (var tempWriter = array.CreateWriter())
            base.WriteJson(tempWriter, value, serializer);
        var token = array.Single();

        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String && value != null)
        {
            var enumType = value.GetType();
            var prefix = enumType.Name + "_";
            token = (JValue)string.Join(", ", token.ToString().Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).Select(s => (!char.IsNumber(s[0]) && s[0] != '-') ? prefix + s : s).ToArray());
        }

        token.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it wherever you could use [`StringEnumConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonConverters.htm), for instance:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new TypePrefixEnumConverter() } };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Comment: that's great exactly what I was looking for and now I understand more precisely json converter. Thanks !