# C# Modify JsonReader when overriding StringEnumConverter

Tags: c#, json, enums, overriding

What I want to do is take the property Value and assign a new value to it:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
    {
        reader.Value = "Item" + reader.Value; //--> This is what I want to accomplish
    }

    return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
}
```

Of course this can't be done this way because reader.Value is read only. Is there any other way I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Actually, yes: 1) Load a `JToken` from the `reader`.  2) Modify the `JToken` as necessary.  3) Call `base.ReadJson()` on `token.CreateReader()`.  There's an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32057245/3744182).  Is that answer sufficient or do you need something more specific?

Comment: Hi @dbc that was exactly what I was looking for. Post it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @IvnBam - since both questions are explicitly subclassing `StringEnumConverter` I went ahead and marked it as a duplicate. You can vote up that other question & answer if you want.  I think your question may have a better written title though.

Comment: @dbc - ooh yeah I hadn't realized it was you who answered that question too. I up voted you there, thank you