# Json.Net - Deserialized to an Enum in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Json.Net to deserialize

I have a c# class that has a property of this type of enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  House,   
  Cat,
  Dog
 }
```

The Json I have:

```
    "MyEnum ": "House",
    "MyEnum ": "Cat",
    "MyEnum ": "Doc<woof>"
```

`House` and `Cat` deserializes, but `Dog<woof>` of course doesn't. How can I get Json.Net to ignore or handle the `woof` ?

Comment: Perhaps a custom JsonConverter for this type/enum? (not sure though if JsonConverter can be used for customizing enum serialization, never did that myself...)

Comment: What happens now (e.g. exception is thrown)? What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Why keep the `<woof>` part in the first place? An enum is the wrong type to use here if your values are not themselves valid enumerations.

Comment: That's not valid json, you appear to have duplicate keys.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How can I ignore unknown enum values during json deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22752075/3744182).  Agree?

Comment: Or if you want to actually strip off the `<woof>` and deserialize to `Dog`, see maybe [Json.net Custom enum converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32057245/3744182).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to define a [custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm). This might look something like this:

```
class MyEnumConverter : JsonConverter<MyEnum>
{
  public override MyEnum ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, MyEnum existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    var token = reader.Value as string ?? reader.Value.ToString();
    var stripped = Regex.Replace(token, @"<[^>]+>", string.Empty);
    if (Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(stripped, out var result))
    {
      return result;
    }
    return default(MyEnum);
  }

  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, MyEnum value, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
  }
}
```

Then decorate your enum with a [[JsonConverter]](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeClass.htm) attribute:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyEnumConverter))]
enum MyEnum
{
  House,
  Dog,
  Cat,
}
```