# clojure - defn/def in function body or let statements

Tags: clojure, defn

```
user=> (defn make-list [] '(1 2 3))
#'user/make-list
user=> (defn get-list [] (map #(str "foo" % ) make-list))
#'user/get-list
user=> (get-list)
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: user$make-list  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
user=> (defn get-list [] (let [ml (make-list)] (map #(str "foo" % ) ml) ))
#'user/get-list
user=> (get-list)
("foo1" "foo2" "foo3")
```

Why can the value from defn not be accessed in the same way from the BODY of a function as it can from the LET clause?

Comment: makeList is a function. You can not map over a function. Try (map #(str "foo" %) (makeList)) instead.

Comment: such a dumb question, I am tempted to delete it. Have decided to leave it as a testament to my idiocy and as advice to others who mess up like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defn` declares a function so you need to invoke it in order to get its result:

```
(defn make-list [] '(1 2 3))
(defn get-list [] (map #(str "foo" % ) (make-list)))
(get-list)

;; ("foo1" "foo2" "foo3")
```

But since your `makeList` function doesn't do anything but return a list, you can use `def` instead as it simply declares a *var*:

```
(def make-list '(1 2 3))
(defn get-list [] (map #(str "foo" % ) make-list))
(get-list)

;;("foo1" "foo2" "foo3")
```

Lastly, use [*kebab-case*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17820138/1562315) instead of *camelCase* for function and var names in Clojure. That's the convention unless you're declaring Protocols or Types.

Comment: You avoid the question. Why does the call site (let or function body) make a difference to the success of the call?

Comment: oops - you are right ... I just left off the bloody parens on the function body!