# How to include html files properly

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to include a css file using this code :

HTML code:

```
<html ng-app="a">
    <head>
         <cssA></cssA>
    </head>
    <body><script src="app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

AngularJS

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('a', []),

    app
        .directive("cssA", function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: "multiple-css.html"
            };
        });
}());
```

multiple-css.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https:/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

How do I please include that html file ?

Comment: css file in html extension???

Comment: @BijayRai, that html file include other css files. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive names are normalized.

In HTML they should be spinal-case:

```
<html ng-app="a">
    <head>
         <css-a></css-a>
    </head>
    <body><script src="app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

In JS, they are camel-case:

```
app.directive("cssA", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: "multiple-css.html"
        };
 });
```

Comment: Wow ! It's the second upvote I give to you. I'm seeing progress here :) (Although, I have no idea what `spinal-case` means. In Angular docs they refer to it as `snake-case`, I believe...)

Comment: Thanks ExpertSystem:) I'm trying to be more careful with my wording and assumptions. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Its interesting that Wikipedia thinks snake case is variables with underscores, but variables with dashes are 'spinal case' or 'kebab case'. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case. This seems to be supported by the SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273282/whats-the-name-for-snake-case-with-dashes. I wonder if the Angular docs are not using the correct terminology, or maybe it doesn't really matter.