# View Component as a Tag Helper does not get Invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Invoking a View Component as a Tag Helper was introduced in ASP.NET Core 1.1. (See [“Invoking a view component as a Tag Helper”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components#invoking-a-view-component-as-a-tag-helper)). But the following only returns the *Test for VC* part of the view. It seems that `<vc:annual-orders>…</vc:annual-orders>` part does not get invoked at all.

**Views\Shared\Components\AnnualOrders\Default.cshtml**:

```
@{ 
    Layout = "";
}
<div>Test for VC</div>
<div>
    <vc:annual-orders>

    </vc:annual-orders>
</div>
```

**myProj\ViewComponents\AnnualOrdersViewComponent.cs**:

```
public class AnnualOrdersViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly OrdersContext _context;

    public AnnualOrdersViewComponent(OrdersContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var lastOrders = _context.Where(t => t.orderType == "new");
        return View(await lastOrders);
    }
}
```

NOTE:

1. I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.1 and the View Components without Tag Helpers are working fine.
2. I also followed MSDN's official tutorial, [“Invoking View Components as Tag Helpers”](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/aspnetmonsters/ASPNET-Monsters-81-Invoking-View-Components-as-Tag-Helpers) where it explains that PascalCase class names and method parameters for the Tag Helper are translated into their lower [kebab-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273282/whats-the-name-for-hyphen-separated-case/12273101#12273101).

Answer (score 15):

This doesn't address your specific situation since your view component is parameterless, but as it's closely related, I’m leaving it here for anyone that needs to hear it:

Even if the tag helper is correctly registered in e.g. the `_ViewStart.cshtml`, [as per @alan-savage's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47563967/3025856), **it will not render unless you include *all* parameters from the `InvokeAsync()` method**.

This may seem self-evident, but it can be confusing since it doesn't respond with an exception, nor is there any (obvious) design-time validation built into **Visual Studio**.

> *Note:* There actually *is* design-time validation, it’s just not *obvious*. In the code editor, correctly referenced view components will show up with **bold property names**. But this is easy to miss if you're not looking for it. And there isn't e.g. a warning that shows up in the *Error List* panel, or as part of the build output.

So, for example, if you instead had:

```cs
public class AnnualOrdersViewComponent : ViewComponent 
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string labelName) 
    {
        … 
    }
}
```

And then called your tag helper as:

```html
<vc:annual-orders></vc:annual-orders>
```

Your code will compile without warning, and your page will run without exception—but the view component will not be rendered.

**In fact, prior to ASP.NET Core 6, this would even happen if you made the view component parameter *optional***, as the [tag helper syntax didn’t honor optional parameters](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5011):

```cs
public class AnnualOrdersViewComponent : ViewComponent 
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string labelName = null) 
    {
        … 
    }
}
```

> *Note:* As of ASP.NET Core 6 Preview 6, View Components called as Tag Helpers will now honor optional parameters ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5011#issuecomment-594340314)).

Obviously, in either of the above examples, this could be fixed by simply including all parameters:

```html
<vc:annual-orders label-name="Contrived Example"></vc:annual-orders>
```

Again, this doesn't address the specifics of your problem, but I imagine developers running into this issue will likely come across this thread, so I wanted to include this as another troubleshooting step in case the tag helper has already been correctly registered.

Comment: **Update:** As of ASP.NET Core 6 Preview 6, Microsoft has implemented support for optional parameters when calling View Components as Tag Helpers ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5011#issuecomment-852574232)). I’ve updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I wonder how to make wrongly specified vc tags fail. There should be at least a warning or a compile time error if the <vc ... /> is not properly resolved IMHO. Otherwise, a refactoring might break views without anybody noticing.

Comment: The bolding of params is the clincher.  I had a subtle misspelling of the assembly name after renaming the assembly.  Added to_ViewImports.cshtml @addTagHelper *, correctAssemblyName and the params lit up like a christmas tree :-)  Easy to miss that they are not.  Good catch.

Answer (score 9):

I have been struggling with this and finally managed to get tag helpers for view components to work.

The issue I had was that the tag helpers were not working on the views within Areas. To resolve this, I copied the `_ViewImports.cshtml` and `_ViewStart.cshtml` pages from the `/Views` directory into `/Areas/<AreaName>/Views` directory. The the tag helpers now work and Visual Studio is giving me IntelliSense on my properties.

Don't forget to add to the `_ViewStart.cshtml` files (where `<AssemblyName>` is the name of the assembly containing the View Components:

```
@addTagHelper *, <AssemblyName>
```

Comment: Just discovered that AssemblyName is case sensitive, even on Windows.

Comment: Aside, I forget to (re)register my tag helpers pretty much every time I introduce a new area. This, alongside remembering to include the `[Area()]` attribute in my control(s), account for more troubleshooting time that I care to admit, since the source of neither issue is immediately obvious based on the output.

Comment: For ASP.NET Core 3.1, I discovered that when using View Components from a [Razor Class Library (RCL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), the consuming website has to use the `@addTagHelper` as stated in this answer to add the RCL assembly, even when the View Components are consumed inside views of the RCL.

Answer (score 7):

this does **Not** work.

```
@addTagHelper *, MyProject.Components
```

this works

```
@addTagHelper *, MyAssemblyName
```

it takes assembly name, not name space.