# Does the Case-Style for Http-Headers have a name?

Tags: http, standards

The odd bird when it comes to casing,

```
Cache-Control
```

etc.

Does the case-style have a formal name?

(And the question is not resolved by referering to known kebab-case etc.)

Comment: Kebab case it is?

Comment: Pascal-Kebab in that case.. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the name for hyphen-separated case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273282/whats-the-name-for-hyphen-separated-case)

Comment: My humble proposal: Great-Kebab, or maybe more catch: Capital-Kebab ;)

Comment: Hyphenated-Pascal-Case?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Junior to Expert](https://juniortoexpert.com/en/naming-convention/) it is called "Train case", but also known simply as "HTTP header case"

> #### Train Case
>
> The train case, which is formed by the combination of kebab
> case and pascal case rules, is also known as HTTP header case. It is
> formed by capitalizing the first letters of the words that make up the
> variable and separating these words with a hyphen (-).

However, in my opinion, "HTTP header case" might be misleading since the http standard only says that header names (or rather field names) are case insensitive.