# Escaping characters in CSS class selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I'm trying to implement [this W3](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#cssescapes) description of character escapes in CSS class selectors.

I'm running into problems with the `abc\20 def` syntax that puts a space after the escape sequence to ensure `def` is not misread as part of the character code.

Specifically, trying to put `abc\XY def` into an HTML class attribute or into a command like `jQuery().addClass('abc\\20 def')` (the `\\` here is part of the JS string literal syntax; the string value itself has one slash) will both give the element two classes, `abc\20` and `def`.

Is this syntax just badly implemented, and I should stick with the six-digit leading zero form? Or does that document only refer to the escape format in CSS code, and the HTML attribute / jQuery argument require some different form of escaping the space character?

**Edit**: Thank you very much for explaining, everyone!

I now understand that this syntax only applies to CSS code - not the class names themselves as set in HTML attributes or Javascript.

This also means that characters designated as whitespace *can't* occur in CSS class values, and no kind of escape mechanism allows them to be added. (Specifically, if I understand correctly, the CSS selector `.abc\20 def` is valid and selects elements with the class `abc def`, but is meaningless because no element can have this class.)

For my concrete use case, which involves **mapping arbitrary values (which *can* have white space) to valid class names**, I need to define my own escape scheme. Replacing whitespace with `-` or `_` (thanks Praveen) is one possibility; if the mapping needs to be one-to-one, replacing them with six-digit Unicode hex values (eg. `"abc def" -> "abc\000020def"`  is a more robust one.

The important thing to keep in mind is that this replacement affects the class name itself - to refer to the class `abc\000020def` in CSS, the backslash must be escaped again, to form the selector `.abc\\000020def`.

Comment: Indeed, that is a tangled evil mess your'e stepping into, mind if I ask why would you need (or want??!) to do this?

Comment: That syntax is evil. Try using `-` or `_`.

Comment: You can say that "the appropriate approach is using dash" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560813/why-are-dashes-preferred-for-css-selectors-html-attributes
. But you should not create a rude comment and give minus because you do not like his way. It is not wrong because you don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Arashsoft I don't downvote unless a proper amount of time has passed and OP has either abandoned the question or has not complied to properly ask the question according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). I do not believe I  nor Praveen was rude, if OP is insulted and informs me so, then I will apologize.

Comment: Putting aside the question of rudeness, I don't think that's what the OP even meant by "this syntax" in the first place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are getting confused between the class name as present in the DOM, and the escaped version required in CSS. The class name is just specified as is:

```
elt.classList.add('foo:bar')
```

It is when this is referenced in a CSS file (or other CSS selector context, such as `querySelector`) that it must be escaped:

```
.foo\:bar { color: red; }
```

The same applies to the case where you choose to use a numeric escape:

```
elt.classList.add('1234');

.\31 234 { color: red; }
```

However, no amount of escaping will permit you to have spaces in class names. Spaces are absolutely reserved for delimiting multiple class names on the DOM `className` attribute.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed to know, thanks! In other words, what I need is to define my own mapping that converts arbitrary values to a valid class name (eg. by replacing spaces with "-" or "\000020") and then just use the mapped class name everywhere.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: DOM parses whatever selector you pass to it as string. If the (parsed by DOM) result contains spaces or non-breaking-spaces, they will count as class separators.

---

You shouldn't worry about jQuery, or any other ECMAScript misinterpreting the spaces meant for ending an escape block as a class delimiter.

*Simply put, because **they are not in charge of this matching***. Document Object Model is. The same DOM that interprets the escaped CSS classes. So if an escaped class name works in your stylesheet, it will work as a selector if passed by any JavaScript library.

> **On one condition:** that it gets passed to DOM in a form that it understands. *A form that **works in CSS***.

Now, let's assume that, for semantics reasons, you'd like to use the class `100%` on an element. You'll need to escape at least the first and last characters for your selector to work. The ones in the middle may or may not be escaped. Possible selectors, all translating at DOM level to the `100%` class name, would be:

- `.\31 00\25`
- `.\31 0\30\25`
- `.\31\30 0\25`
- `.\31\30\30\25`
- `.\31 \30 \30 \25`

As you already know, there are more [escaping CSS methods](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes). However, this applies to all.

When you pass a selector to jQuery or JavaScript it will treat it as a string and pass it to the DOM parser. However, these libraries have their own escaping mechanisms, allowing us to do fancy stuff. So, to allow any of the above selectors to make it to the DOM parser you need to escape the backslashes, so they are not misinterpreted by JavaScript as escape characters and removed from string.

**Basically you need to double your backslashes.** Any of the following will do:

- `.\\31 00\\25`,
- `.\\31 0\\30\\25`,
- `.\\31\\30 0\\25`
- `.\\31\\30\\30\\25`
- `.\\31 \\30 \\30 \\25`

Here's a snippet. Test it out. Add elements with class `0%` and you will see they don't get selected. Because the DOM parser will turn any of the above selectors into `100%` and match them against the `100%` class you have put to the element.

```js
$('.\\31\\30\\30\\25>div').on('click', function(){
  var positions = ['first','second','third'];
  alert('You clicked the ' + positions[$(this).index()] + ' div.');
})
```

```css
.\31 0\30\25 > div{
  padding: 20px;
}
.\31 00\25 > *:first-child {
  color: red;
}

.\31\30 0\25 > *:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}
.\31\30\30\25 > *:last-child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="100%">
        <div>first</div>
        <div>second</div>
        <div>third</div>
    </div>
```

---

Getting back to your example (`abc\\20 def`) it will parse and behave exactly like `abc def`. ***Spaces***, when present in the final result of the class name string, **will be  interpreted as class delimiters**. This goes for both `\x20` and `\xa0` (space and non-breaking-space) and it is the expected behaviour.

As an interesting (trivial) note, if for some evil reason you wanted to make it hard for people to style up your app, you could always add a `command` type character to a class name. Here's an example:

```js
$('.space').removeClass('\x73\x70\x61\x63\x65').addClass('\x1a\x73\x70\x61\x63\x65');
```

```css
.space {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="space">
  inspect me, i should be red!
</div>
```

Comment: Agreed. The only thing stopping it just short of answering the question, though, is that it neglects to address the space character specifically, which is the entire reason for this question in the first place. That is addressed now in torazaburo's answer.

Comment: Both `space` and `non-breaking-space` characters are interpreted as class delimiters. Updated the answer. Thank you for pointing my omission out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `class="abc&amp;#x0020;def"` to solve that problem