# Django forms - hyphens instead of underscores in names of IDs

Tags: django, django-forms

In HTML, the best practice is to use hyphens instead of underscores in names of ids.For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560813/why-are-dashes-preferred-for-css-selectors-html-attributes) refers to this issue.

However, Django for some reason uses underscores when automatically generating ids from the names of the model fields. Is it possible to override this behaviour somehow ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do anything but overriding the [`id_for_label()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.3/django/forms/widgets.py#L259) method on a per-widget bases:

```
def id_for_label(self, id_):
    return id_.replace('_', '-')
```

But if using hyphens might be better practice in HTML, doing so much work just to have hyphens instead of underscores seems overkill and counter-productive.

Another solution would be to [monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) django but it seems overkill to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of reasons you would want to modify the HTML id. Underscores are ugly when mixed with hyphens!

Use [`auto_id`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#configuring-form-elements-html-id-attributes-and-label-tags).

> By default, auto_id is set to the string 'id_%s'.

You could define this when initializing the form:

```
form = MyForm(auto_id='id-%s')
```

or change it in the initialization of your form class:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'auto_id': 'id-%s'})
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Modifying `id_for_label(self, id_)` in a custom widget too:

```
# widgets.py

class MyTextInput(widgets.TextInput):
    class Media:
        css = {'all': ('myapp/widgets/css/mycustominput.css',)}
        js = ('myapp/widgets/js/mycustominput.js',)

    def id_for_label(self, id_):
        return id_.replace('_', '-')

# forms.py

from .widgets import MyTextInput

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    widgets = {
        'text': MyTextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    }
```