# Using - over _ in CSS to support "older" browsers

Tags: css

I am refactoring some CSS and figured I would review based on [this](https://www.pragmaticpraxis.com/sketchbook-2/?preview_id=2585&preview_nonce=b5c8f8653f&_thumbnail_id=-1&preview=true) helpful best practices reference. One thing that is mentioned in using **`-`** instead of **`_`** in naming types, and of COURSE I named all my types with **`_`**! The reference mentions doing this for "older browser" compatibility, but not what this means exactly. Is this IE6 level stuff, where I can (in my opinion) safely ignore anyone still using that junk? Or is this IE9 level stuff, where I know a ton of my readers are still in IE9? And, what are the implications with Android browsers? Knowing that Android basically stops getting updates the moment you buy the phone in some cases, am I gimping myself there as well if I don't bother to refactor?

Comment: Your link is not publicly visible.

Comment: what? who uses IE9 nowadays?

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560813/why-are-dashes-preferred-for-css-selectors-html-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Those naming used to override CSS attributes for specific browsers, and they are bugs/hacks in browsers that allow you to style browser with that found bug to behave as intended. check [browserhacks](http://browserhacks.com/) for more information about this, also [browser specific css hacks](https://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/)

example

```
body {
  background-color: red;
  _background-color: blue;
}
```

this CSS will be apply red background to the body and they will ignore `_background-color: blue;` because its invalid CSS attribute, but for IE6 it will recognize it as a valid CSS attribute (because IE6 CSS validator will sanitize it and remove the leading `_`) and will override the `background-color: red;`

Comment: So, curious if this is leading underscores only are a problem? All of my naming uses Px_ as a prefix, then more underscore infixes as needed. Likely I'll do some reading tonight and see what else I can learn, so thanks for those links!

Comment: your name is not wrong for the selector, but in the attribute nowadays we don't use them anymore (to my knowledge not much people using them after IE6 - IE10 are not supported by Microsoft).