# How do i get Min and Max value of Bootstrap slider?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following slider in my razor

```
<input id="rbSlider" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[0,1000]" />
```

On Click, i need to get its current Min and Max values.

i tried using following without luck,

```
    var min = $('#rbSlider').data('slider').min;
    var max = $('#rbSlider').data('slider').max;
```

Its returning not defined error, How do i get min and max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh finally i got it working using the following

```
var min = $('#rbSlider').data('slider').options.value[0];
var max = $('#rbSlider').data('slider').options.value[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it. The attributes `data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="1000"` can be accessed like this:

```
var min = $('#rbSlider').data('sliderMin');
var max = $('#rbSlider').data('sliderMax');
```

Note that I have removed the `-` and used CamelCase. Take a look at the [API](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and you will see that jQuery takes `$( "div" ).data( "lastValue" ) === 43;`:

> ... searches among the attributes of the element, converting a camel-cased string into a dashed string and then prepending data- to the result. So, the string lastValue is converted to data-last-value.

So for consistency, use camel casing (just watch out [for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286607/jquery-camel-case-mapping-from-data-attribute-names-to-data-keys))

Comment: @jc uenod, hey i am back again, the reason its not working now. Slider not returning the correct Min and Max values. It always returns data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="1000" values.  It was working fine before.

Comment: @NithinPaul If it was working before, then it's not a result of this code - check your console.

Comment: @NithinPaul are you trying to get the current value?

Comment: Yes, I need currently selected Min and Max value. Even if there is no slider action occured, i need whatever the value its holding as Min and Max

Answer (score 2):

You were so close. Try this.

```
var min = $('#rbSlider').data('slider-min');
var max = $('#rbSlider').data('slider-max');
```

Comment: hey i am back again, the reason its not working now. Slider not returning the correct Min and Max values. It always returns data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="1000" values. It was working fine before

Comment: This solution returns current value, u need to check if current values are changed, accordingly it will give results.

Comment: I checked this, but it is only returning 0 and 1000 from data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="1000" not its current selected value. What i am doing is when slide change occurs, i calls a script function to get the value from this $('#rbSlider'). But value none other than min value 0 and max value 1000

Comment: min and maxvalue are always static i think, you need current value?

Comment: Yes exactly. I need currently selected Min and Max value. Even if there is no slider action occured, i need whatever the value its holding as Min and Max

Comment: Here value is retrieved from slider. Also can I know, How to set value for the slider and reflect in UI.

Answer (score 1):

**Improvement for dynamically set limits**

@jcuenod's answer will retrieve the min/max values as set in the initial HTML's DOM. However, if you are changing the limits later via JavaScript (i.e. `$("#rbSlider").slider('option', {min: 5, max: 100})`), this will not get you the up-to-date values

Instead, you need to use `$("#rbSlider").data('slider').options.max`

Answer (score 0):

```
var min = $('#rbSlider').slider('option','min');
var max = $('#rbSlider').slider('option','max');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.